# How do I get started with building a Community Connector for Data Studio?

Tags: javascript, rest, looker-studio

I would like to build my own community connector for Google Data Studio. Nothing overly complex, first of all I just want to understand how it works. Fortunately Google provides a nice tutorial on how  to do this: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/build
Unfortunately, I'm a little overwhelmed by it. I just started coding and I have a basic knowledge of JS, HTML and CSS. It seems like further knowledge is required to get the most out of the tutorial. Could you guys hint me in a direction? What do I have to learn in addition? I would also appreciate recommendations for learning resources.

Have a nice day and thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, having a very breif look this is just JavaScript. If you're overwhelmed I suggest using the following website(s) as they're great JavaScript resources: http://javascript.info/ & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Since you have basic knowledge of Javascript, I suggest you start with the [Community Connector Codelab](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started). The codelab has detailed step by step guide and uses the npm download API as an example. However, if you are already familiar with an API that does not require any authentication, you can start with that as well.

The [Build guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/build) you linked to can be the second step after you have completed the codelab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already read through the tutorial, but what I'm searching for is some material to understand more deeply what is going on there. For example I have practically zero knowledge about API's. However, this could be helpful, wouldn't you agree? I don't just want to build it but understand what I'm building.

Comment: In that case, let me turn the table around and ask why do you want to build a Data Studio Community Connector? The most common use case is that people want to fetch data from a certain API.

Comment: And this is exactly my use case as well.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you learn about web APIs in general first. Then familiarize yourself with the API you are trying to fetch data from. Unfortunately, this is much broader and open ended topic that cannot be covered via the connector documentation / tutorials.

Comment: Perfect. Can you recommend any ressource for doing that?

Comment: *web API*: This is a vast topic. I suggest googling this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Introduction and https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/ can be good places to start.

*specific API*: Read the documentation for the API you are interested in.